# How to Query and Arrange Two Similar Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one student table links to two scores tables which are exactly the same structures. The only different is that one table will stores high scores, the other table stores low scores. Now I need to query both high and low score tables, it will list all subjects scores with student name if it is from high score table and scores with name is `student` if its from low score table, and I need to order the result by time.

```
SELECT u.student_name,
       a.subject1_score,
       a.subject2_score,
       a.subject3_score,
       a.subject4_score,
       a.subject5_score,
       a.exam_date
FROM   Student u
INNER JOIN High_Score_Table a
On u.student_id = a.student_id
ORDER  BY a.exame_date = time
```

Then for `low_score_Table` I will have almost same query except that the student name will equal to `Student` by default.

Then I will need to put this together in a list and order by time. How could I do that shorter and better ?
Btw, I can merge two tables low and high_score into one, and add a column called "flag" into that, whenever the flag value equal to "show" then I show student name with all score records, else "hidden" I will just show "Student" and all score records. How could I do that in one query ?

Comment: You need to use `ON` clause instead of `where` clause. Also try to add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `UNION`, because you are concatenating two distinct result sets - one from `High_Score_Table` and one from (presumably) `Low_Score_Table`:

```
select s.student_name,
       h.subject1_score,
       h.subject2_score,
       h.subject3_score,
       h.subject4_score,
       h.subject5_score,
       h.exam_date
from High_Score_Table h
join Student s on h.student_id = u.student_id
union all
select 'student' as student_name,
       l.subject1_score,
       l.subject2_score,
       l.subject3_score,
       l.subject4_score,
       l.subject5_score,
       l.exam_date
from Low_Score_Table l
order by exam_date
```

The takeaway here is an `ORDER BY` clause in a union sorts over the entire result set - which is in this case exactly what you want.

Comment: I think in select from Low_Score_Table query also need "join Student s on l.student_id = u.student_id" ?

Comment: by the way, in case the exam_date is different from two scores tables, how to order that in one query above?

Comment: I can merge two tables low and high_score into one, and add a column called "flag" into that, whenever the flag value equal to "show" then I show student name with all score records, else "hidden" I will just show "Student" and all score records. How could I do that in one query ?